# getting the c00ce514 error in IE when attemping to load a swf file

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, flash

I have the following ajax call inside an .each loop, that loads several .swf files from the server:

```
$.ajax({
   url: src, //a variable containing the url of the swf file
   success: function(){
      //success code.
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(textStatus+' - '+errorThrown);
   }
});
```

This works like a charm on all browsers, except for IE. Some .swf files are loaded, and some are not.

The error I get is the following: **Could not complete the operation due to error c00ce514.**

I googled about this error, and found that this is due a charset issue or something like that; some people offered solution regarding html/xml files, but I'm not sure how to fix this for a .swf file. Any ideas/workarounds?

Comment: I am having the same problem with preloading wav files, also only crushing at IE :-( Would love to know the solution :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this ticket:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11426

If I get it right:
IE cannot handle binary files as a response in AJAX calls, so you have to prevent IE from executing the call. Preloading a swf in IE does not seem to be possible with an AJAX call.