# could not complete operation due to error c00ce514

Tags: ajax

I have this code as an excel downloader. After the excel has been generated.
But I'm having an error. As stated in the question Title.

The error occurs at the line:
**var strResponeText = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;**

```
var strUrl = "POSSellThroughReportExcelOpener.aspx?getstatus=1&DateFrom=" + hdnDateFrom.value + "&DateTo=" + hdnDateTo.value + "&customer_id=" + hdnCustomerID.value + "&intdisplayby=" + hdnDisplayBy.value + "&monthorweek=" + hdnMonthOrWeek.value;
if (XMLHttpRequestObject) {
    XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", strUrl);
    XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if ((XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4) && (XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)) {
    var hdnRedirectUrl = document.getElementById("hdnRedirectUrl");
    var strResponeText = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
    var intResponse = new Number(strResponeText);
    var spanCallBackStatus = document.getElementById("spanCallBackStatus");
    var trClose = document.getElementById("trClose");

    if (!isNaN(intResponse)) {
          if (intResponse == 1) {
             spanCallBackStatus.innerHTML = "Excel Report has been generated."
             trClose.style.display = "";
             Init();
             window.location.href = hdnRedirectUrl.value;
          }
          else {
        GetStatus();
          }
     }
     else {
           spanCallBackStatus.innerHTML = strResponeText;
     }
}
}
    XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Many thanks.

**UPDATE - FEB 20,2014 3:55PM (PHILIPPINE TIME)**

Hi Guys,

I have found the cause of the error, it is because the content-type is called two times. During Page_Load event and at last line of the Generate Excel function which is not supposed to be. That is why the current content-type after the page loads has been replaced after the generate excel function. Hehe my bad I guess.

Anyway thanks for all the help, advice and useful links.
Good day to all. :D

Comment: Welcome to the site! Does the browser throw that error, or does `strResponeText` contain it?

Comment: What is the content of the excel file? This error usually occurs when the characterset of the file does not match to your page. Have a look at [this](http://nevyan.blogspot.in/2008/12/easy-solve-ajax-c00ce514-error.html)

Comment: @Ed Cottrell - The browser is the one who throws the error.

Comment: @Rohan - Here is the content type: "APPLICATION/VND.MS-EXCEL"

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting the c00ce514 error in IE when attemping to load a swf file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783330/getting-the-c00ce514-error-in-ie-when-attemping-to-load-a-swf-file)

Comment: Did you change the Content-type of the requested file? I think changing that would solve your problem

Comment: @Rohan as of now that what I'm trying to do. Will be back later. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer can't handle binary responses to AJAX requests like XMLHttpRequestObject, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783330/getting-the-c00ce514-error-in-ie-when-attemping-to-load-a-swf-file). You need to handle the response in some other way, depending on what you need to do with it.

Comment: I have other excel generating screens that I used as a reference, everything was the same except of course to the variables or parameters passed. All the other excel generating screens are working smoothly but this screen is not. That is why it's a bit frustrating. Hehe.